# Webdriver getting a null point exception

Tags: junit, selenium-webdriver

This sample of code below returns a `null pointer exception`. Why is that?

```
public class JunitCheck {

WebDriver driver;
public String baseURL = null;


@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {


    baseURL = "https://www.google.com";
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {


}

@Test
public void test() {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.get(baseURL);
    System.out.println(baseURL);

}
```

Comment: This code works for me. You need to me more specific than this. Where does the error show up? Could you post the relevant part of the stack trace? Which version of WebDriver are you using, which version of Firefox? Have you tried another browsers?

Comment: Did u have the selenium-server-standalone-2.xx.0 jar in your lib folder? If selenium jar is not present, then in that case too eclipse will throws the same error

Answer (score 0):

You probably must set your `baseURL` as `static`.

Update : static or not it works for me.

Check your imports :

```
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
```

Comment: I have check my import, even when I am not using Junit I am getting the error.

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.NullPointerException, this is the error message I am getting with the huge list follows..

Comment: At what line is the `NullPointerException` being thrown?

Comment: First Line it throws,I am using the Eclipse for the first whenever I initialize WebDriver it throws an null pointer exception. but otherwise it's working fine without WD.